# Setting priority on std::async thread

Tags: c++, posix, std

When using std::async, what is the best way to set priority? I realize this is platform dependent, but with a posix compliant operating system, would this work?

```
// Launch task with priority 8
auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, // async policy required
   [] ()
   {
      pthread_setschedprio(pthread_self(), 8);
      // do work
   });
```

I've found answers about std::thread, but not for std::async.

**Edit**. In my case I am on a QNX operating system. So I believe setting the priority like I've done above is valid. However, it does seem like there are valid concerns raised about whether or not the priority will persist after the async task is complete (depending how async is implemented).

**Edit2** Potential options seem to be...

- Leverage std::thread (perhaps with a thread pool) to keep explicitly managed threads at a given priority
- Justify in my situation that setting the priority is not necessary.
- Create an RAII class to change priority back to the original at the end of the async launched lambda.

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to mix concepts like that. I understand the desire to use the modern c++11 API, but if that thread comes from a thread pool, the priority will stick.

Maybe you'll want to use pthreads natively for this?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: You could set the priority back at the end of the task.  (Or make a little class to do it RAII-style.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your design is a bad idea.

`std::async` is required to behave as-if it was a new `std::thread`.  But it doesn't have to be on a new pthread.  The implementation is free to (and probably should) have a set of underlying threads that it recycles for `std::async` -- just clean up `thread_local` storage and handle stuff like `set_value_at_thread_exit` it would work (under the standard).

Accessing the underlying pthread and messing with its priority, in that case, might impact later async tasks.

I cannot state certainly this would happen, but I found on at least one system that there is an underlying thread pool -- the symptom was that after a certain number of `std::async`s new ones waited to be scheduled for old ones to finish.  On a low-core system, this caused a deadlock in some insufficiently paranoid code (the dependency chain of waiting for other threads got larger than the thread pool size, so the last task wasn't scheduled).  That deadlock shouldn't happen under the standard; but it is evidence that platforms do use thread pools for async.

Consider making your own thread pool on top of `std::thread`, and implementing something `async`-like on top of it with a priority.  If you are keeping `std::thread`s around and managing the priority yourself that is less likely to cause problems.

For `std::thread`, you can get its `native_handle`, which on your system is probably a pthread handle.

Comment: There is this `std::lauch` to set the async lauch policy. This allows for "lazy evaluation". It would be nice to have "lazy priority". It would execute with lower priority while not needed and higher priority when evaluation is required. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes it will work. Be cautious about thread pools. I *think* `std::launch::async` doesn't use thread pools because it guarantees immediate launches and this would also interfere with any `std::promises` that use `set_value_at_thread_exit`. But `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` may use a thread pool so this priority will affect future async calls if you are not careful.

A fix would be pretty simple: Just set up a destructor that changes the priority back to the original.

However, note that you are misusing the pthread interface. At least on Linux you will get an EINVAL error as noted here: [pthread_setschedprio() fails with "EINVAL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140505/pthread-setschedprio-fails-with-einval)
Basically, priority is not supported for normal scheduling. You would have to switch to real-time scheduling via FIFO or round-robin first.

What you are probably thinking of is the `nice` value. But that is per-process as far as I know. What you can do is lower the thread priority by changing the policy to `SCHED_BATCH` or `SCHED_IDLE`:

```
const sched_param param{};
pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_BATCH, &param);
```

Be very cautious about priority inversion when using these. Batch and idle scheduling lower the priority severely more than a simple `nice` value.

Comment: In my case, I am actually on QNX, so I believe setting the priority as I have above does work. Interesting to know, though, that setting a simple priority wouldn't work by default on Linux.